# Angular4 + Angular CLI supporting Javascript AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-cli

Is it possible to get angular4 + angular CLI to support Javascript files?

I have a legacy angularJS application written in javascript that I want to import components from in my Angular4 application using the upgrade module.  The current problem I am facing is that the angularCLI doesn't seem to be loading/building the included javascript components/files in the project that I added.

I am currently following this guide which doesn't mention getting javascript angularjs components into angular4: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Thanks!

Comment: Worst case, just change file extension from `.js` to `.ts` on the JavaScript files

Comment: are you trying to use js libraries in your ts files ?

Comment: Yes!  I assumed it would work as it is all converted to JS in the end anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> Anything you can do with Angular in TypeScript, you can also do in
> JavaScript. Translating from one language to the other is mostly a
> matter of changing the way you organize your code and access Angular
> APIs.

you may find documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/ts-to-js).

Comment: So what you are saying is to not bother trying to get the build to support javascript and instead convert the components to typescript?

Comment: No, you may choose whatever language you want to use, I am unaware if angular-cli supports JavaScript builds. But you can very well write your own build from scratch, having said that as mentioned in the link, `TypeScript is a popular language option for Angular development. Most code examples on the Internet are using TypeScript`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `declare` keyword in `typescript`. Try link your old angularjs file into `html` with script tag. Then `declare` that component which you want to use from old angularjs in Angular 4/typescript like:

`declare var YourComponent;`

More about `declare` http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2013/07/22/quick-tip-typescript-declare-keyword/